# Magento 1.7 CE, Admin layout messed up when editing a product

Tags: magento, admin, product

I am currently using magento 1.7 for my website http://tuicoach.vn

This is my first post after searching all posts for this issue. I have modified the frontend including style.css in my skin (display:none for Vertical nav in sidebar) & product List style to remove Compare & Wishlist.

Other than this, I didn't touch anything on admin folder. Is there any reason why I got like the attached when I select a product to edit?

The main editing area now got inside the sidebar navigation for admin.

Much appreciate. I am fraid I have to completely reinstall.

http://i270.photobucket.com/albums/jj85/dinhung85/magento_zps0375d89f.jpg

I cannot post images so I put the link here to help explain the situation.

Comment: Have you install extension related to product?

Comment: Can you check if any JS error occurs during edit page loading ?